# How can i check a named route is defined or not in laravel 5.5 before redirect

Tags: laravel-5.5

How can i check a named route is defined or not in laravel 5.5

can i check a route is present in routes/web.php file by using the name of the route?
please help

Comment: Use `Route::has()`

Comment: Thanks..it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

#### To check a route is exist or not.

```
if(Route::has('route.name'){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
```

Above code will return *`true`* if a route name exists.
Otherwise it fails and return *`false`*.